# Unable to create PostgreSQL user over TLS using createuser

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, postgresql

I need to create a new PostgreSQL user on a remote PostgreSQL 13 server from on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine. createuser and psql (postgresql-client) are on the Ubuntu server. I was hoping I could use createuser to create the user like this:

```
createuser -SDRP -U pgadmin -h myserver.myurl.com -p 5433 -d defaultdb
```

Normally when connecting to my server I use:

```
psql -U pgadmin -h myserver.myurl.com -p 5433 -d defaultdb sslmode=require
```

I don't see any option to specify that TLS is required with createuser - am I missing it? I'm unable to use it without TLS for the connection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't use both -D and -d  with creatuser

Answer (score 2):

libpq allows you to use a connection string in place of the database name.
so, with libpq based tools, anywhere you can use a database name you can use a connection string.

```
 createuser "host=myserver.myurl.com port=5433 dbname=defaultdb sslmode=require user=pgadmin" -SDRP username_to_create
```